# Where are the issues in this conversion from VRML to X3D?

Tags: x3d, x3dom, vrml

I have a [legacy VRML project from 2003](http://arts-infoscape.org/) with a couple of VRML models. I converted the VRML to X3D (so I can load them with X3DOM) with [InstantReality converter](http://doc.instantreality.org/tools/x3d_encoding_converter/).

One model is incomplete with missing colours and shapes, the other doesn't appear at all.

Here are the converted pages (view source) and the original VRML models:

- [X3D model 1](http://arts-infoscape.org/vrml/t1.html)
- [VRML model 1](http://arts-infoscape.org/vrml/t1.wrl)
- [X3D model 2](http://arts-infoscape.org/vrml/b2.html)
- [VRML model 2](http://arts-infoscape.org/vrml/b2.wrl)

I'm looking for some direction as to where the conversion is failing, or how to edit the resulting X3D code to fix the elements that aren't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct answer is that the X3DOM implementation does not support the Prototype nodes that are in the VMRL and translated X3D files, so even a perfect conversion would not be rendered in X3DOM.

The X_ITE javascript-WebGL implementation ( http://create3000.de/x_ite/getting-started/ ) does support these X3D nodes.

That being said, the files you provided reference several others, so I am not able to really test how X_ITE does with the converted files.

The Web3D Consortium supports a user community that, I think, would be interested in this application and would be able to provide more advice. They can be reached at the website: http://www.web3d.org ; and public mailing list https://www.web3d.org/mailman/listinfo/x3d-public_web3d.org

Comment: that works with the original VRML files! E.g. see: https://daveeveritt.github.io/arts-infoscape/vrml/t1.html - now to the rest of the update…

Comment: Already encountering issues I can't easily identify/fix (see my [last VRML/X3D question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60027233/123033)), so I've joined the public mailing list as recommended :-)

Comment: X3DOM now supports Proto's in XML and JSON.  Either provide an Inline element with a .json file extension in the url attribute, or there may be a way to do it with pure XML that Andreas Plesch worked on.   Sorry I didn't see this sooner.  But yeah, as far as I know, X_ITE provides much better Proto and VRMLScript support (but X3DOM has HTML Script, which requires an extension in X_ITE).